# Testing reliability of regression coefficients

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-coefficients, linear, marginal-effect

If I run a logit/linear regression for the purpose of measuring marginal effects and estimating the causal impact of a specific independent variable on the dependent variable, is there a reliable way of understanding that the results (coefficients and marginal effects) are credible? I understand that one way is to measure if the p-value is small enough and/or the standard error for a given coefficient/marginal effect is not too large but in practice, these measurements don't seem to be good enough to finally say whether or not your coefficients are reliable. Is this more of an art than a science?

If the former, are there any assumptions to consider to better understand the credibility of results. For instance, in the case of a binary treatment variable is it best to have an equal sample size in both groups of treatment, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

P values don't tell you whether the variable is reliable or not (if I understand what that means). It tells you if the null hypothesis that that variable does not have impact can be rejected or not. But not how strong that impact is. Regressions, statistics generally can not say anything about causal relationships. Your design can to some extent, for instance if using random assignment and reasonably generalizing to your population. But the statistics itself can never tell you that. It is best to have good statistical power, enough cases to reasonably generalize to your population and to measure with limited error :) These are design/measurement issues primarily. Making sure the regression assumptions are met is important, but can not insure you can generalize or measured without error. In my humble opinion much of the statistical literature tends to ignore these issues and focus on the internal statistics. More attention to design and data measurement (**before** the statistics is run) is critical, but downplayed in the literature. Part of the reason is that a lot of researchers have limited say in these areas, they do not collect the data, but obtain it from other sources. Another part is fragmentation in academics, so that design of measurement is separate from statistical analysis, both are not taught together. The issue of whether one can generalize from the initial data is particularly questionable...

Comment: Makes sense, i supposed my question is more around a scenario in which you're performing an observational study and therefore did not have any chance to design the experiment and include randomization. More broadly speaking, how can I perform a statistically rigorous analysis (and validate that rigor) when performing a regression on a set of data that was not a part of a controlled and randomized experiment.

Comment: the only thing that know of is to test if the assumptions are met. Do tests of non linearity, heteroskedasticty, etc. Check your statistical power. Tell your audience of any potential limitation that you are aware of. Doing sensitivity test, what if there is this much error, what would that lead to, are probably a good idea if you know how to do it (I don't and have been too lazy historically to do this). My guess is that non-linear or non-stationary data, and data that can not be generalized are the greatest problems.